# How to fetch image through json using jquery or JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Can any body help, m totally new in Json I want to fetch the image but m bit confuse in the array and object thing. Or is it possible to fetch image without img tag. Thank you in advance

[This is my JSON link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt)

this what I have tried:

```
function myFunction(worldpopulation) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<worldpopulation.length; i++)
        out += '' + worldpopulation[i].rank;
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

just help me to fetch "rank" only

```
{ "worldpopulation": 
    [
         {
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":2,"country":"India",
         "population":"1,210,193,422",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":3,"country":"United States",
         "population":"315,761,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
         }, 

    ]
}
```

Comment: please include a small part of your JSON as example in your question, or it will become obsolete and useless to other SO users as soon as this .txt/json file gets removed from the server... It is also quite unclear to me what you're exactly trying to achieve and what are the current and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will get the content of your json content from this page using XMLHttpRequest

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt";
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState == && request.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
```

the implementation of myFunction

```
function myFunction(myArr)
{
    for(var i=0; i< myArr.length; ++i) {
        var img ; // get your element you want to place img inside
        img.src = myArr[0].flag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.filter()` to get `image` array.

```
var imageArr = [];
   imageArr = worldpopulation.filter(function(val,indx){
   return val.flag;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery in following way

```
$.getJSON( "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt",function( data ) { 

  $.each( data.worldpopulation, function( key, country) {
   console.log('Image Url',country.flag)
  });
});
```